# You can only take address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer error in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, implicit-conversion, unsafe-pointers

I did reverse engineering of a project using .NET Reflector everything is fine Instead of this error I don't know how I can solve it please guide me Thanks in Advance. Here is the code.

> CS0212    You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer

```
if (flag6 && !double.IsNaN(doubleValue))
{
  double* numPtr1 = &this._MeasData[index].MeasValSum;//Error(You can only take address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer)
  numPtr1[0] += doubleValue;
  int* numPtr2 = &this._MeasData[index].MeasValNoOfValues; //Error(You can only take address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer)
  numPtr2[0]++;
}
```

and the _MeasData Struct is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MeasChData
{
  public MeasureInfo MeasInfo;
  public int MeasChNumber;
  public RollingPointPairList MeasureSamples;
  public LineItem MeasuredValueLine;
  public double MeasValSum;
  public int MeasValNoOfValues;
  public double MeasValLabel;
  public double CurrentYMin;
  public double CurrentYMax;
}
```

I tried casting but failed to sort out this error.
I'm not good in English. So ignore if....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem this way

```
fixed(double* numPtr1 = &this._MeasData[index].MeasValSum)
numPtr1[0] +=doubleValue;
fixed( int* numPtr2 = &this._MeasData[index].MeasValNoOfValues)
numPtr2[0]++;
```