# CS0212 Error using dll with unsafe code: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, unsafe

The (incomplete) snippet

```
unsafe class MainWindow
{
     ...
     IntPtr somePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
     unsafe private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         NamespaceFromReferencedUnsafeDll.SomeFunction(&somePtr)
     }
     ...
}
```

}

Is supposed to call `SomeFunction` from a managed Dll with unsafe code, to set the pointer `somePtr`, but results in the compiler error

> CS0212: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside
> of a fixed statement initializer

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045618/you-can-only-take-address-of-an-unfixed-expression-inside-of-a-fixed-statement-i), the `fixed` keyword has to be used in some way, but

```
fixed(IntPtr somePtr = IntPtr.Zero);
```

didn't help.

How can I fix this (no pun intended) ?

Comment: Pass `out somePtr`, then no unsafe code is needed. The `extern` declaration may need to be adjusted likewise. Note that if you are intending to actually call the function rather than treat it as an opaque value things get more complicated, and you need things like `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the signature of

```
SomeFunction
```

in the referenced unsafe dll.

After changing

```
public static unsafe uint SomeFunction(IntPtr* somePtr)
```

to

```
public static unsafe uint SomeFunction(out IntPtr somePtr)
```

the snippet

```
class MainWindow
{
     ...
     IntPtr somePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
     private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
            NamespaceFromReferencedUnsafeDll.SomeFunction(out somePtr)
     }
     ...
}
```

compiles without errors and works at runtime.

Comment: Note that `unsafe` can be removed everywhere (in this part of the code at least), since passing `out IntPtr` is perfectly safe in managed code. It's also generally good practice to restrict `unsafe` to specific blocks rather than apply it to entire methods or classes -- ideally the unsafe bits are wrapped with code that is safe.

Comment: Thanks, please review the updated version of the answer.